# Appium failing with UiAutomator2 driver - Error executing adbExec

Tags: testing, automated-tests, appium, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

Whenever I try to launch Appium Inspector, it gives me the following error:

Failed to create session. An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C:\Users\Andrius\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 install -r --no-incremental C:\Users\Andrius\.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk' exited with code 1'; Command output: adb: failed to install C:\Users\Andrius.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Existing package io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test signatures do not match newer version; ignoring!]

I am using Android Studio Virtual Device (API 33).

On Appium Inspector I am using this configuration:

```
{
  "appium:deviceName": "emulator-5554",
  "appium:automationName": "UiAutomator2",
  "appium:app": "C:/Test.apk",
  "platformName": "android"
}
```

I have reinstalled the emulator via Android Studio, made sure the developer mode is enabled;
Checked that the device exists with 'adb devices', it appears with the same name as I've put in the configuration of Appium,
Reinstalled Appium and UiAutomator2 driver;
Made sure that the file shown in the error actually exists;
Tried running the app on the emulator itself without Appium, it works.

It has worked up until today, I have done nothing to the configurations of any devices/programs involved, I have not even touched my computer in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

Test.apk application is already installed on the emulator. Remove the old one first and try again